# Get sub categories in A to Z order of a particular category

Tags: category, menu

How do it get sub categories in A to Z order of a particular category in each  block and label them alphabetically. Note that A, B, C, etc. are just label.

For example:

**A**

- A sub category 1
- A sub category 2
- A sub category 3

**B**

- B sub category 1
- B sub category 2
- B sub category 3

**C**

- C sub category 1
- C sub category 2
- C sub category 3

Answer (score 0):

if you are using your own menu extension you can use like below

```
$currentCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(3);
    $collection = $currentCategory->getCollection();
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('url_key')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('all_children')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('is_anchor')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1)
        ->addIdFilter($currentCategory->getChildren())
        ->setOrder('name', Varien_Db_Select::SQL_ASC)
        ->load();
```

if you are using any custom block to render this use cache for this and Also make sure it would not take much load in your page.

hope this will work for your.